# Remove sub captions from list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I have this code. In my list of figures "subcaption1" and "subcaption2" appears. I only want "hej" to appear in the list of figures, how can I do that?

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Chapters/xxxx.jpg}
    \caption{subcaption1}
    \label{fig:chapter001_dist_001}
  \end{minipage}
  \hspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Chapters/xxxx.png}
    \caption{subcaption2}
    \label{fig:chapter001_reward_001}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{hej}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `subfig` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
%%
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \subfloat[][\label{fig:chapter001_dist_001}subcaption1]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \hspace{0.06\linewidth}
  \subfloat[][\label{fig:chapter001_reward_001}subcaption2]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
  \caption{hej}
  \label{fig:chapter001__001}
\end{figure}
In Figure~\ref{fig:chapter001__001} there are two figures, Figure~\ref{fig:chapter001_dist_001} and Figure~\ref{fig:chapter001_reward_001}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

As requested in comments here is also a solution using the `subcaption`package. There the subcaptions are not listed in the list of figures by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}% [list=true] to get caption in listoffigures
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
%%
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.47\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{subcaption1}
    \label{fig:chapter001_dist_001}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hspace{0.06\linewidth}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.47\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{subcaption2}
    \label{fig:chapter001_reward_001}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{hej}
  \label{fig:chapter001__001}
\end{figure}
In Figure~\ref{fig:chapter001__001} there are two figures, Figure~\ref{fig:chapter001_dist_001} and Figure~\ref{fig:chapter001_reward_001}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you extend you answer adding also an example with subcaption package?

Comment: @gvgramazio, I have added it. That is probably a better solution.